# IllegalStateException on MediaRecorder.start()

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, android-mediarecorder

Morning!

I have a weird problem with a production app. Some users get an IllegalStateException on a MediaRecorder start. I cannot reproduce the problem on the few devices I own or even on an emulator. This error occurs on different versions and devices, (Android 5 to 10 and every kind of devices), and has many occurrences.

Here is the code

```
if (mRecorder == null) {
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        } else {
            try {
                mRecorder.stop();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(128000);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
        mRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
        mRecorder.setMaxDuration(mMaxDurationInMs);
        mRecorder.prepare();
        mRecorder.start();
```

And the stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: null
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.native_start(MediaRecorder.java)
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(MediaRecorder.java:1603)
    at de.boxine.someapp.util.media.VoiceRecorder.start(VoiceRecorder.java:115)
    at de.boxine.someapp.recording.audio.RecordAudioPresenter.startRecording(RecordAudioPresenter.java:186)
    at de.boxine.someapp.recording.audio.RecordAudioPresenter.startRecordingByAvailableSource(RecordAudioPresenter.java:204)
    at de.boxine.someapp.recording.audio.RecordAudioPresenter.access$500(RecordAudioPresenter.java:27)
    at de.boxine.someapp.recording.audio.RecordAudioPresenter$2.onPermissionGranted(RecordAudioPresenter.java:116)
    at de.boxine.someapp.mvp.AbstractPresenter.checkPermissionBeforeRun(AbstractPresenter.java:67)
    at de.boxine.someapp.recording.audio.RecordAudioPresenter.onRecordButtonClicked(RecordAudioPresenter.java:108)
    at de.boxine.someapp.recording.audio.RecordAudioFragment.lambda$onCreateView$0$RecordAudioFragment(RecordAudioFragment.java:112)
    at de.boxine.someapp.recording.audio.-$$Lambda$RecordAudioFragment$9H7EZrHdPKO0BFbM_UTVYf_SFBU.onClick
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6659)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6631)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:790)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26187)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

I also have these permissions in my manifest (I ask them realtime on the recent Android versions)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you please add your error log when it throws IllegalStateException?

Comment: @Jaymin I added it

Comment: is your application record call?? @DenisPinna

Comment: do you reset or release the recorder after stop?

Comment: No, it's to record realtime with a button clicked by the user when he's on the application.

Comment: okay then try as @Jaymin said. reset and release after stopping

Comment: I already do it. The call thing could be the problem, at least I can produce the same error now. Thanks for this!

Comment: @DenisPinna, Great! Just debugs the code, You will find the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for the help. I think the problem in my case was that the phone was in a call (or other communication app).

To prevent this I added this check before

```
public static boolean isMicrophoneAvailable() {
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) MyApp.getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        return audioManager.getMode() == MODE_NORMAL;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The use case I generally use is, I create the instance of the media recorder and start when the user presses the button. once the recording is finished and the user presses the stop button then I release the media recorder.

Here is my piece of code:

```
private fun startRecording() {

        mRecorder = MediaRecorder()

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare()
            mRecorder.start()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }   
    }
```

When the user presses the stop button then invoke the stopRecording method.

```
 private fun stopRecording() {
        mRecorder.stop()
        mRecorder.release()

    }
```

The same this you can apply in your application.

**Note: The code is in Kotlin.**

Comment: Hi @Jaymin, are you sure it could come from this, prepare() should me synchronized by default? Did you already have the case?

Comment: Yes, It will work fine. I will synchronize by default. You just have to replace the code and check.

Comment: I do not think it's the problem in my case, also it's a MediaRecorder and not a MediaPlayer, there is no such method on this one.

Comment: @DenisPinna, I have updated the code. Please have a look.